# Comparison and re-structuring of 3 lists into a single list?

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

So I have the following:

```
class Item
{
    string Name;
    bool IsSelected;
}
```

And I have 3 lists:

```
List<Item> list1;
List<Item> list2;
List<Item> list3;
```

My objective is to translate the above into a single collection where similar 'Item' objects are grouped together (similar = objects that have the same 'Name').

So I want:

```
List<ItemContainer> resultantList;
```

where:

```
class ItemContainer
{
    string Name;
    IList<Item> items;  //items with the same 'Name' (potentially)
}
```

Notes:

- The lists can have different number of items.
- An 'Item' object can belong to only one list. It's just that we can have different objects with the same 'Name' in different lists.
- If no other object with the same 'Name' could be found, it would
  still need to be included in the resulting list.

What would be the most concise and the clearest way of implementing this?

Note: performance is not an concern.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for `ItemContainer` to have a `Name` property?

Comment: Yes you're right. I updated my code.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's super simple to do with LINQ, but even a foreach loop would do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx),

```
var groupyName = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).GroupBy(I => I.Name);
```

Comment: Then just `foreach (var g in groupyName)`. `g.Key` will be your `Name` and you can create a `new List<Item>(g)` for your `items`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it:

```
itemContainer.items = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3)
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(item => item.Name)
                    .ThenByDescending(item => item.IsSelected)
                    .ToList();
```

Here is a full example of what you ask,
Do notice you do not require a `GroupBy` as the return value from grouping is not identical to the new list you wish to receive.

You do need to override the `Item` methods for `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object obj)` as the `Distinct()` will use them automatically to compare between items.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item {Name = "A", IsSelected = true},
                new Item {Name = "B", IsSelected = false},
                new Item {Name = "C", IsSelected = true}
            };

            var list2 = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item {Name = "A", IsSelected = true},
                new Item {Name = "C", IsSelected = true},
                new Item {Name = "D", IsSelected = false}
            };

            var list3 = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item {Name = "B", IsSelected = true},
                new Item {Name = "E", IsSelected = false},
                new Item {Name = "F", IsSelected = false}
            };

            var itemContainer = new ItemContainer();
            itemContainer.items = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(item => item.Name)
                .ThenByDescending(item => item.IsSelected)
                .ToList();

            //new list of items will contain 7 items:
            // A,true
            // B,true
            // B,false
            // C,true
            // D,false
            // E,false
            // F,false
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public bool IsSelected;

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode() * IsSelected.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var objItem = obj as Item;
            return objItem != null && objItem.Name == Name && objItem.IsSelected == IsSelected;
        }
    }

    public class ItemContainer
    {
        public string Name;
        public IList<Item> items;  //items with the same 'Name' (potentially)
    }
```